# Reporting Services - Two filters on the same chart Category Group?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts

I have sales data that I'd like to plot on my chart. However, at a specific point in time, we had a change taking place I'd like to ensure is clearly visible in the chart, preferably by dividing the sales data (which is stored in a single SQL Server column) into two different chunks, which would allow me to then treat them as different data series.

I used to solve this in Excel by storing the post-event data in a different column (by simply dragging them to a different column), and thus I was able to treat them as a different series (the blue and green line in the chart below. The red and orange line are pre-event and post-event averages):

[image]

I'd like to reproduce this effect in SSRS, but am not sure how to tackle it. I've tried using an approach where I added two category groups, both pointing to the date-time column, and applying filters to them (one `<=` the cutoff date, the other `>=`).

I then added my sales data twice, with the idea I could somehow connect them to the individual category groups, but that does not seem possible.

Has anyone tried anything like this before, or would have a different approach to achieve what I'm trying to get?

Thanks!

Comment: What specific version of SSRS is this?

Comment: @IanPreston - SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this to work, and figured I'd share how to do it.

My dataset contains a field called `DATEKEY`, which stores the date in the format `YYYYMMDD`. It's possible to use this in an expression and evaluate the date for a specific row. In case the expression evaluates to true, we display the value. If not, we display a blank string.

In case we want to show the values prior to the date, the expression would be:

```
=IIF(Fields!DATEKEY.Value <= 20130601, Avg(Fields!My_NUMBER.Value), "")
```

The second series can then be made by reversing the symbol:

```
=IIF(Fields!DATEKEY.Value >= 20130601, Avg(Fields!My_NUMBER.Value), "")
```

The graph then looks like this:

[image]